# How to fix 'Could not find default template, or template not valid.' error with SMTP Pro in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have installed SMTP Pro Aschroder Extension in Magento 1.9. I have not changed any code. but I have changed country and Timezone from backend. Now I am getting below error.

Test email was sent successfully.
Could not find default template, or template not valid, or email communications disabled in Advanced > System settings.
Please check that you have templates in place for your emails. These are in app/locale, or custom defined in System > Transaction Emails. Also check Advanced > System settings to ensure email communications are enabled.

Comment: You will need to add the code that is causing this error for someone to be able to answer it. Remember to properly format it, thank you.

Comment: I have not done any changes in coding. I have changed country and timezone from Magento admin.